# Swap a pointer to the allocated memory with a common pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, swap

I want to swap two lines in a matrix. My matrix is an allocated solid block of memory.
I have an array of pointers that point to the rows of the matrix. The first pointer points to this big allocated block. And other pointers point to different parts or this block.

If I swap any two rows, except the first, it's OK. But I have problems with the first row.
I guess that's because the pointer to the first row is different from other. But what is the main difference?

```
#include <iostream>

int** allocateMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
    // allocating array of pointers (rows)
    int** matrix = new int*[rows];
    // allocating one solid block for the whole matrix
    matrix[0] = new int[rows*cols];

    // setting the pointers for rows
    for ( int i = 1; i < rows; ++i ) {
        matrix[i] = matrix[i-1] + cols;
    }

    // fill the matrix with consecutive numbers
    int k = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < cols; ++j ) {
            matrix[i][j] = k;
            k += 1;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

void freeMatrix(int** matrix) {
    delete[] matrix[0];
    delete[] matrix;
}

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    int m = 3;
    int** matrix = allocateMatrix(n, m);

    // swap the first and the second line
    int* tmp = matrix[0];
    matrix[0] = matrix[1];
    matrix[1] = tmp;

    // print matrix (it is printing ok)
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // problem is here
    freeMatrix(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a matrix class which contains a `vector<vector<int>> data` member, and implement a swap function which calls `std::swap` on the data variable, or one of its rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that the first pointer was returned by `new[]`. Deleting that pointer will deallocate the entire memory block, but deleting any other pointer in the array will have undefined behaviour.

You could store the pointer which you get from `new[]` separately, and have a duplicate "weak" pointer to the first row that you keep in the array of row pointers.

Comment: Thank you. I think I thought about it not much.
Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work if you swap first (0) and second (1) rows because you are using `matrix[0]` to delete the memory allocation.

You need to somehow "keep" the original allocation, e.g.

```
 int *origalloc; 

 ...
 origalloc = matrix[0] = new int[rows*cols];


 ... 
 delete[] origalloc;     // Instead of malloc[0];
```

What you pass to `delete` or `delete []` must the the same pointer-value as what you get back from the `new` or `new []`. Anything else is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you too. If I could give the second answer I would give it you too.